# compiling allegro on code blocks/vs15 errors

Tags: c++, codeblocks, allegro, allegro5

I have a coding assignment and I have been plagued by this issue, when I finally configure my compiler and libraries linked I get these 100+ errors although the code is correct ( copied  from teacher's webpage )

here's the code :
http://pastebin.com/2WCgcAEy

and the errors I get

[image: errors]

I somehow got it to work in dev c++ but I forgot how and I uninstalled the software, visual 2015 is a nightmare to work on, and code blocks is frustrating....

Comment: The `_imp__*` names indicate that you use some DLL, but you still need to link with a .lib to resolve those names.

Comment: Do you really need to compile Allegro with VIsual Studio? If the task consists  of **using** the library but not compiling it then your best bet will be to use the NuGet packages for VS2015. That is the easiest way on all platforms to use Allegro.